# How to stop postDelayed after x number of times

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am creating an animation that randomly selects a string that's pulled from an XML string array. It does this in rapid succession to make it look kind of like a slot machine. I got the animation going, but I do not know how to stop it after x times. Here's what I have thus far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView locationsTextView;
    Button generateBtn;
    String[] mArray;
    int counter; //<-- This is how I would like to keep track of when handler should stop
    Handler h = new Handler();
    int delay = 50;
    Runnable runnable;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationsTextView = findViewById(R.id.locationsTextView);
        generateBtn = findViewById(R.id.generateBtn);
        mArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations_array);
        locationsTextView.setText("");

        generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        updateTextView();
                        runnable = this;
                        h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
                    }
                }, delay);
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateTextView() {

        Random random = new Random();
        int maxIndex = mArray.length;
        int generatedIndex = random.nextInt(maxIndex);

        locationsTextView.setText(mArray[generatedIndex]);
    }
}
```

I am thinking that something like this would work:

```
//pseudo code
//Button is clicked
//initialize counter to 0
counter = 0;
//updateTextView method is called repeatedly
counter ++;
if(counter == 50) {
    h.removeCallbacksandMessages(null);
}
```

I just don't know where I would place that in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If I would've taken a few more minutes before posting, I think I figured it out. See code below:

```
generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter = 0; //<-- every click, set back to 0
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        counter++; //<-- increment with every method call
                        updateTextView();
                        runnable = this;
                        h.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
                        if(counter == 50) { //<-- stop after 50
                            h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                        }
                    }
                }, delay);
            }
        });
    }
```